# psycopg2 - Poor performance fetching data from Redshift to Python

Tags: python, amazon-redshift, psycopg2

I am trying to retrieve data from redshift to python with psycopg2. Somehow, it takes ages (40 minutes) to load a 35GB database on my python server.

```
import psycopg2
con = psycopg2.connect(db_connection_info)

query_cursor = con.cursor('query_cursor')
query_cursor.execute('my_query')

stop = 0
batch = 0

print('Starting to retrieve data')

while stop == 0:
    tmp = query_cursor.fetchmany(10000)

    if len(tmp) < 1:
        stop = 1
    else:
        if batch % 100 == 0:
            print(str(batch*10000) + ' rows loaded')
        if batch == 0:
            data = tmp
        else:
            data = data + tmp
    batch = batch + 1

print('Transfering data to dataframe')

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data, columns = manually_selected_features, coerce_float = True)
```

I am not using pd.read_sql because I need to use a server side cursor for RAM reasons.

I am clueless as to why the first iteration of fetchmany is taking a really long time compare to others.

Is there a good way to speed up my query ?

Regards,
Xavier

Comment: how long does you query take without python?

Comment: It is approximatively 10x faster to retrieve the data

Comment: first run of any query is slow on redshift. as it is "compiling" - could this be the reason?

Comment: I don't know, the execute part takes less than 1 second, fetching the data seems to be my issue as far as I understand it